# Intermittent 404s using LinkedIn Sign In API 

Tags: php, api, linkedin-api

I am using PHP and the LinkedIn Sign In API on my website. After logging I got an array with:

```
TDjhOAiGm3
Sushil
Kandola
Software Engineer at Cyberlinks
http://media.linkedin.com/mpr/mprx/0_T_Ic9xfOWkQcs7E1_G4k9jjOdb-ZsoI1ik0e9pDY9C6e5mpPD5RRZyMKFdtbJDo088ddJUxfFs4y
```

But sometimes I get:

```
404
1336026813751
ZJQ0Y92V0S
0
Could not find person based on: ~
```

Despite receiving **Auth Id**, I am getting a **404**. Can anybody help me get the correct info?